# How to parse a specific column or data without losing content from other columns after parsing?

Tags: linux, shell-script

ORIGINAL QUESTION AND BODY IS EDITED: I have the following output to grep the value in this case "225". This value is dynamic so it could change depending on input" but I want to get the full row that has a value of 225 based only on matching pattern from column 4 without losing the content of the whole row.

```
Input:
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/2|DeviceX_4021|LG
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/3|Undiscoverable|Unkwn
10.20.225.10|2000-H1|1/1/5|DeviceZ_2050|LG
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore

Desired Output
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore

The following output its not desired:
10.20.225.10|2000-H1|1/1/5|DeviceZ_2050|LG
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

I have tried many awk and greps without success. Keep in mind I have a value of 225 at first column, row 3; so I dont need that output. Just need all that matches "225" on Column 4. Now file is delimited with pipe without any spaces.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear how the columns are delimited

Comment: Are your columns separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: Hi; Its separated by both tabs/spaces... Using "paste command" and also spaces

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 ~ /[^0-9]225[^0-9]/' file
```

This matches `225` in the fourth field and prints the record where the matched value is not preceeded or followed by a number (like `1225` or `2256`).

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like it's well-formatted for awk:

```
$ awk '$8 == "225)"' INPUT
10.20.225.207        Device #1            1/1/23  Brand #2 (MODEL: 225)         LG
10.20.209.252        Device #2            1/1/36  Brand #2 (MODEL: 225)         LG
```

We use 8th column because awk separates columns by whitespace by default.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez: I don't know what you're talking about. What column 5? Output of this command is exactly the same as the desired output you posted in your question. Printing the entire line (_record_) is the default action awk does when condition matches.

Comment: Doesnt work. Try it for yourself

Comment: @JavierGonzalez  Tried it independently (LInux Mint 19.3, GNU Awk 4.1.4). It works exactly as your input  and output appear in the question. Maybe you should show your actual command and output, not just say it does not work. My guess is you wrote `$0` instead of `$8`, or `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you:

`grep 'MODEL: 225)' input-file`

Assuming the value `225` is always preceded by `MODEL:` .

Comment: This will also match `MODEL: 22512397619283769123` or anything else that starts with `255`. You could try `grep 'MODEL: 225)'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with perl and with sed. Would be nice if we can do it with awk.

Solution A thanks to Dave Cross

- perl -aF'|' -ne '$F[3] =~ 225 and print' < input

Solution B thanks to John Bollinger

- sed -n '/^([^|]*|){3}[^|]*225/p' < input